# Keyset pagination using UUID v4

Tags: mongodb, go, uuid

Rather than using skip-limit, I want to paginate my documents by sorting it using created_timestamp.  The 2nd page will check for timestamp older than the last record of 1st page.  However, I use UUID v4 for my PK and don't know how to handle tie breaker since it doesnt have order on it.

```
package repository

import (
  "github.com/google/uuid"
)

.
.
.
item.ID = uuid.New().String()
```

I would like to ask:

1. Is there any way to handle tiebreaker besides using PK?
2. If there is no other way, how do I generate UUIDs that are time ordered using the google uuid library?

Comment: 1) Any unique field will do. 2) You can't. Why do you think (random) UUIDs can't be compared (and thus ordered)?

Comment: @Peter sorry, u meant it doesnt hv to be time ordered to be a tiebreaker? how can i use it

Comment: To break a tie you just need something that is guaranteed to be distinct for any two documents. Simply order by that field second.